# How to use jQuery Validate's errorPlacement and showErrors simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I recently removed the messages function from my validation. I then placed in jQuery validate's `showErrors` function so that I could get the borders for the required inputs to change to red. At this point, everything was working well until I added `showErrors` with it.

The reason for adding `showErrors` is that I wanted a simple message to appear, instead of multiple, and the borders to still show as red.

From my snippet below, you will see that only `showErrors` is currently working. Is there anyway to get both of these to work simultaneously. If so, how?

Alternatively, here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04owax5s/2/)

Adjusted JS

```
errorPlacement: function() {
        return false;
    },
     showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        $('#formErrors').html('All fields must be completed before you submit the form.');
        this.defaultShowErrors();
    },
    submitHandler: function() {
                submit();
    },
```

```js
$('#catalogRequestForm').validate({
  ignore: [],
  rules: {
   first_name: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2
   },
   last_name: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2
   },
   address1: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 5
   },
   city: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2
   },
   state: {
    required: true
   },
   zip: {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    minlength: 5
   },
   email: {
    required: true,
    email: true
   }
  },
  errorPlacement: function(){
            return false;
        },
   showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
   $('#formErrors').html('All fields must be completed before you submit the form.');
  },
  submitHandler: function() {
              submit();
        },

});
```

```css
.error {
 border: 2px solid #b82222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" id="catalogRequestForm">
  <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name *">
  <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name *">
  <div id="formErrors"></div>
  <input id="requestSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.defaultShowErrors()` within `showErrors` to reactivate the default message behavior.  Since you have a `return false` within `errorPlacement`, you only see your styling and not the messages.

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) { // <- disable default errorPlacement
    $('#formErrors').html('All fields must be completed before you submit the form.');
    this.defaultShowErrors(); // <- re-enable default errorPlacement
},
```

[**Read more**: jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors)

By only containing `submit()`, your `submitHandler` is completely broken.  If that is your real function, then remove the `submitHandler` entirely because a regular form submit is already the default behavior.  Otherwise, if you're doing something before the submit, then you'll need to pass a `form` argument and attach it to `.submit()`.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {  // <- pass 'form' argument into function
    // do something, then submit
    form.submit();  // <- attach 'form' argument to '.submit()'
}
```

**DEMO**:

```js
$('#catalogRequestForm').validate({
  ignore: [],
  rules: {
    first_name: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2
    },
    last_name: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2
    }
  },
  errorPlacement: function() {
    return false;
  },
  showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    $('#formErrors').html('All fields must be completed before you submit the form.');
    this.defaultShowErrors();
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
  },

});
```

```css
.error {
  border: 2px solid #b82222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" id="catalogRequestForm">
  <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name *">
  <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name *">
  <div id="formErrors"></div>
  <input id="requestSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**jsFiddle version:  [jsfiddle.net/ryoufcqh/](https://jsfiddle.net/ryoufcqh/)**

Comment: Not sure what I am doing wrong, but the same issue is going on for me.

Comment: @Paul, no idea what that comment means.  My live demo fixes the issue you reported in your OP.  Are you not seeing my live demo above?

Comment: Sorry, terrible explanation on my part. I made changes to my code based on your answer and it results in the same initial issue. I updated my question and posted the new code.

Comment: @Paul, I still have absolutely no idea what you're talking about; the code you're posting is working.   All I did was add this one line to your posted jsFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/04owax5s/3/